# how to input the data of several meteorological stations into a machine learning model?

Tags: python, database, machine-learning, deep-learning, data-science

I have a dataset with 15 different meteorological stations (providing T, rh, wind direction through time).

How should I implement them in a machine learning model? As independent inputs or can I combine them?

If you could provide me with some references or hints to start this project, that would very helpful !

I have so far cleaned the data and separate each meteorological station.
I believe that I should try to perform a single prediction on each station and then combine the prediction of each station together ?

Comment: Do you have training and testing datasets?  If you are attempting to predict the future you might want to try several strategies and find out if one is better than the others.

Comment: yes, I understood that. I don't understand how to analyse the data from the different stations.